# Can I omit 'why' and 'how' from these sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, clauses, redundancy, reduced-relative-clauses

Is the reduction of these two sentences correct?

**1.The reason why I'm single is I'm very shy**.

*The reason I'm single is I'm very shy*.

**2.The way how he talks is so impressive**.

*The way he talks is so impressive*.

Comment: "The way how he talks" is not grammatical.  The way **that** he talks

Answer (score 1):

> 1.*The reason why I'm single is I'm very shy.*
>
> 1a *The reason I'm single is I'm very shy.*
>
> 2.**The way how he talks is so impressive*.
>
> 2a *The way he talks is so impressive.*

1a is an acceptable alternant to 1. A *that* relative is also possible: *The reason that I'm single is that I'm very shy.*

"How" is not a relative pronoun so 2. as written is ungrammatical, though 2a is fine. Note that a *that* relative is also possible: *The way that he talks is so impressive.*

Comment: Why is 2 not grammatical ? Why can't I use 'how'? 'How he talks' is modifying the subject 'the way' .

Comment: _How he talks_ and _the way [in which] he talks_ mean the same, so it's incorrect to use both in the same sentence.

Comment: @SahilLaskar As I said in my answer, "how" is not a relative pronoun, so we cannot have *"the way how he talks".